# How to use separate layout for login component in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new in angular. I create a login component , it works fine fine but issue is that I want a separate layout of login from whole app. What changes required for that?

I search on google but everyone give diff solution which not understandable also.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'alert/:id', component: AlertDetailComponent },
{ path: 'alerts', component: AlertsComponent },
{ path: 'dashboard', component: EriskDashboardComponent },  
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },  
];
```

In app.component.html

```
<!-- page content -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>           
</div>
<!-- /page content -->
```

Comment: what do you mean by **separate login from whole app** ??

Comment: mean I want to use a layout different from other components

Comment: You have to use two `Routes` at the top level (e.g. `login` & `content`) and then put the remaining routes as `children` of `content` route. Please read the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

Comment: where do you want to have your login component. Under which of the above listed routes ? or as a separate module?

Comment: i just want that UI of login is different from rest of app

Comment: The way I see it, you are doing it already. You have your `LoginComponent` when the path is login, and that Component can have a different layout than the rest of your components. Just use a different html template in your `LoginComponent`.

Comment: Did you solve this? Having the same problem right now..

And for others by saying "separate login from whole app" means he has navigation / side bar etc for each route, but for login he doesnt want navigation etc

Comment: Look at this project. 
https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your `app.component.html`:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then create `MainComponent (main.component.ts)` and put all of your main app layout in `main.component.html`:

```
<!-- page content -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>           
</div>
<!-- /page content -->
```

This component will be parent for each your regular app component.

Then in your LoginComponent put different layout without router-outlet, for example:

```
<div class="login-wrapper">
  <div class="login">
   ... your login layout
  </div>
</div>
```

Then modify your routing to be something like that:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '', component: MainComponent, redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full',
    children: [
      { path: 'alert/:id', component: AlertDetailComponent },
      { path: 'alerts', component: AlertsComponent },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: EriskDashboardComponent }
  ]}];
```

So MainComponent will contain all reusable layouts and app structure for any child component, while LoginComponent is independent and it has its own layout.

Comment: if you donot have any problem with an extra route parameter in your app then this is more modular.

Comment: Came here to post this solution. This also has the benefit of only having to AuthGuard one page to hide the entire rest of the app from the unauthenticated user.

Comment: @BennyChan what are the limitations? I'm using similar approach and am able lazy load feature modules without any issues

Comment: This is the best way to go, even with lazy-loaded modules!

Comment: @Bohdan Khodakivskyi, there are several cases, `**` with `404page` not works as expected, and sometimes `sub routing` not works.

Comment: @BennyChan what is that cases? Can you describe it?

Comment: @cutoffurmind when I create another routing module, then it also bypasses the main layout and shows the component on full page.

Comment: @cutoffurmind This answer leads to "Error: Invalid configuration of route '': redirectTo and children cannot be used together". What would be the updated version?

Comment: the whole idea is just to have login page separated from regular app routing, there should be no problems with it even with last angular version guys

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @anton-rusak is perfect. In angular 11 I had the problen "redirectTo and children cannot be used together".

I just removed the full path and redirectTo and it worked fine.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
      { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent },
    ]}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "most" parent component you can `.subscribe` to the `router.events` `data` and once you hit the login component as active route, that component will be notified and add a `css class` or `id` for the different layout(theme) you want (perhaps that would be encapsulated in a partial scss file - if you don't use scss/sass perhaps you should consider it).

Once, you change route (other than login) the class will be gone and the "custom" (different) layout will not be applied anymore.

Hope that might help. You can always use a `@Output`/ `@Input()` or a shared singleton service with observables (for non parent-child components relationship) to share state between those components and do stuff based on state change. If you have any questions/comments feel free to add them. I think angular docs can help with the implementation details.