# Components are using main layout only if routed in app-routing.module.ts

Tags: angular

If I route my component with  another-routing.module.ts, then it doesn't use mainlayout.

MainComponent is like app.component.ts for me, got the idea from the below link. as I wanted to bypass MainLayout for the login page. 
[How to use separate layout for login component in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888873/how-to-use-separate-layout-for-login-component-in-angular-2)

```
App-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "", component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: "help", component: HelpComponent }
    ]
  }
];

another-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'users' , children : [
    {path: 'add', component: UsersComponent},    
    ]}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Layout Component should has a router-outlet tag and your module should be loaded inside the Layout Component.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: LayoutComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'companies',
      loadChildren: () =>
        import('./pages/companies/companies.module').then(m => m.CompaniesModule)
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      redirectTo: 'companies'
    }
  ]
}];
```

That way, all the children οf the Layout Component will inherit the layout component.

Comment: Thanks, Man, it works perfectly. plus lazy loading also solved. :)