# how can I hide div for specific component in angular?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular.

In my app compnent html

I have

```
<div class="A">
<router-outlet ></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Any component loaded will be inside the div.

Can I remove the login component from this ?

I tried this action [How to use separate layout for login component in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888873/how-to-use-separate-layout-for-login-component-in-angular-2)
it is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

The `router-outlet` is responsible for rendering the component instantiated by the router, depending on the current route.

If you want a component to not be rendered at this location and dependent of the matched route, e. g. your `LoginComponent`, you can remove it from your routing configuration (usually at `/src/app/app-routing.module.ts`, or a similar name).

---

While this answers your question as well as possible given your sparse details, I suggest you still want to have the `LoginComponent` in your template, depending on your route. You could achieve this e. g. by

- placing it e. g. somewhere in the root `app.component.html` combined with an `ngIf` to ensure it only triggers at a specific route: `<app-login *ngIf="isInLogin()"></app-login>`, and subscribing on to url changes or checking the location url in the `ts` file
- creating a second `router-outlet`. To make several `router-outlet`s work in one app, you should use the `name` attribute, see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet)
- Add an `ngIf` to the div itself, assuming you anyway want to have a service managing the authentication: `<div *ngIf="!authenticationService.isLoggedIn()">`

Comment: <div class="A">
<router-outlet ></router-outlet>
</div>  <router-outlet ></router-outlet> then hide that ine